# How can i do C++ template in Typescript

Tags: c++, typescript, templates, typescript-generics

I want to know if it's possible to have the same function but for different type like in c++ for Typescript ?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void print(double x)
{
    std::cout << "IS DOUBLE: " << x << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void print(int x)
{
    std::cout << "IS INT: " << x << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void print(std::string x)
{
    std::cout << "IS STRING: " << x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    print<int>(2);
    print<double>(8.0);
    print<std::string>("HA");

    return 0;
}
```

There is the output

> IS INT: 2
> IS DOUBLE: 8
> IS STRING: HA

Comment: there is no need for templates in your example. The same would work with plain simple overloads

Comment: fwiw, Typescript does have function overloading, which is basically "same function for different types [of parameters]"

Comment: Yes, this is a really weird example. The actual template argument provided in the calls e.g. `print<int>(2);` has no meaning here. `print<std::string>(2);` would still print `IS INT: 2`. You could have just removed all `template <typename T>` and `<...>` on the calls and it would work the same way. A more sensible example would be `template <typename T>
void print(T x)
{ std::cout << "x is: " << x << std::endl;
}` which can then be called as `print(/*...*/);` for all types supporting the streaming operator `<<`.